# Cannot call sendRedirect() after downloading PDF

Tags: servlets, command, response, illegalstateexception

I saw many questions like the one I am asking, but they are not exactly about what I am looking for.

I am using `Command` pattern, and want to create PDF-file and download it. Creating is perfect, but when I want to download it, it's starts downloading and throws an exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
>      org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
>      java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Here is my code from Command Pattern

```
@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException, AppException {
    String fontPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath(AppConstants.FONT_PATH);
    DBManager db = DBManager.getInstance();
    String ticketCode = request.getParameter("ticketCode");
    String place = request.getParameter("place");
    int amountTickets = Integer.valueOf(place);
    String flightName = Encoding.encoding(request.getParameter("flightName"));
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("client");
    String locale = (String) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("currentLocale");
    db.updateFlightTickets(flightName, --amountTickets);
    ///////create pdf document and represent it to the byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos =ReportCreator.createReport(locale, fontPath, ticketCode, place, user,
                db.getFlightByName(flightName));
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(baos.size());
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"Ticket\"");
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    return Path.SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is my "success page", sorry but can not add more, not enough reputation

```
        <fmt:message key="success_jsp.label.success" />
```

And here is my servlet code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request, response);
}

private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String commandName = request.getParameter("command");
    Command command = CommandContainer.get(commandName);
    String forward = "";
    try {
        forward = command.execute(request, response);
    } catch (AppException ex) {
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", ex.getMessage());
    }
    if (forward.equals(Path.SUCCESS)) {
        response.sendRedirect(forward);
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(forward).forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Part of code in JSP, where click is calling the servlet

```
<td><a  href="Controller?command=buyTicket&flightName=${item.name}&place=${item.amountTickets}&ticketCode=<token:generate/>"><button><fmt:message key="welcome_jsp.submit.buy_ticket" /></button></a></td>
```

How can i avoid it?

Comment: please post ypur jsp code and how you are calling the servlet

Comment: I did it,  will be gratefull for any help

Comment: where is the jsp code that is calling the servlet

Comment: i think there is nothing wrong with your code , but please check the following link http://www.coderanch.com/t/362152/Servlets/java/Redirect-JSP-file-download

Answer (score 0):

The exception says you are trying to working with the request/response once you redirect it or viceversa, and it's not valid.

Once you redirect a request, you cannot do anything else with the request/response, so getting the output stream and writing something to it is completely insane.

It's true about vice-versa situation, writing something and then redirect it will cause the browser will ignore the response data, or exception on server as I'm guessing you got.(but it depends on container)

So you either do not redirect the browser, or provide the pdf file with the target servlet/cgi where you are trying to redirect.

=================

And your current situation/problem:

Server sets the `content-length`, `content-type`,... and starts to write down some stream to the browser, since you haven't set any status, container will set default `200 OK` which indicates there is some right response for the request.

Then browser will get some data(the pdf file) as `200 OK` data(and consider it done), now how would you redirect the user once the response is almost done?!!?!!?!

I still do not understand why do you like to redirect a request when it's almost closed? you like to redirect the user after download complete? you cannot.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i still can't understand what i have to do. I know why exception is heppens , but cant understand how to avoid it. And, yes, after downloading pdf i want to redirect to the "success page", if i can not do it, can i open downloading in new browser tab, and on the old tab redirect to the "success page"? Give me some code, if you can

Comment: @Ilya Assume user is downloading the file using a download manager, so what does redirect mean here? You may have a client side function which once user invokes the download page, the script redirects the user to the `success` page, and of course open the download in a blank(new) page. Beside you cannot find out about the exact time download will be finished